# height property is not working in mozilla

Tags: css, html

I have a web page , where I had set the height of  body tag  to 1460px .Its works fine  with chrome and IE , but giving problem with firefox .

here is my code :

```
    body{
          background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 1024px 700px;
          background-size: 506px 1379px;
          height: 1460px;
    }
    #mainContainer {
          background: #FFF;
          height: 1250px;
          width: 1192px;
          margin: 105px 128px 125px;
          z-index: 100000;
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px 25px rgba(1, 12, 10, 0.2);
          border: medium none;
          padding-bottom: 25px;
   }
```

maincontainer is a div

Comment: What problem is it giving on Mozilla FireFox?

Comment: Can you throw us a fiddle, using 100^ margin, excessive dimensions of `background-size`, high `z-index`, and excessive dimensions of `height` and `width` as well, you are certainly going in a wrong direction

Comment: If you mentioned  the z-index ,you should be specify the position

Comment: the maincontainer div is seen at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

add this line to top

```
html{

height:100%;

}
```

Comment: This is not required, OP isn't saying about `100%` height of the elements

Comment: Parent element should be set as i know in firefox

Comment: It's need to be set `100%` only if the child elements `height` is set in `%` unit, here, OP is using `px`